# Repository class read from json file, how to read the file?

Tags: c#, json

In the DAL, I have a repository class that is getting the data from a json file. That json file is included in the sln.

The code is using the file's absolute location to create a stream reader, read the file and use JsonConvert.

```
var json = new StreamReaderWrapper(absoluteFileNamePath).ReadToEnd();
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyInfoCollection>(json);
```

I would like to remove this absolute path, I tried to use the resource in the project but I always have a null stream.

```
var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("file");
```

As my json file is in the sln, I changed file the properties to copy always, but it's only copied in the bin folder of the DAL and not in the main executable. So I could not try a relative path approach.

What's the best solution to remove this absolute path? And how will you do it?

Comment: You should tag the type of application that you are using (winform or web application or maybe something else) as you might use a different technique depending on that.

Comment: Are you embedding the json as a resource?  Note that this is different from it simply being a part of the solution.

Comment: Right now the json is in the solution. I added it as a resource and try to retrieve it with the code above but it didn't work, that's why I'm asking on Stackoverflow. It's a WPF application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to GetManifestResourceStream needs to be the formatted with the namespace, path in project and file name. For example:

```
"DAL.SomeProjectFolderForJsonData.Filename"
```

You should also ensure the Build Action of the json file is set to Embedded Resource.

Comment: I'm using calling GetManifestResourceStream with the namespace, path in project and file name. I could not find the build action on the json file. I'm using the vs 2015 community.

Comment: ok, i found the Build Action, set it to Embeded Ressource but still cannot have a stream from GetManifestResourceStream

Comment: @CedricRoyer-Bertrand - try right-clicking on the project file and then select Add->"Existing Item...". This will open a file browser; navigate to your json file (you may need to alter the filter in the lower right hand corner of the file browser). Once you see the file appear in the project, change the Build Action on the file to Embedded Resource. At this point, ensure the argument to GetManifestResourceStream corresponds to my prior instructions.